# R: Using sqldf and insert to create a dataframe

Tags: r, insert, sqldf

I am trying to create a dataframe using sqlf and sql insert.  Here's a simple version of my code

```
d2 = data.frame(x=runif(10))
sqldf(c("create table d1(min_x real, max_x real)", 
        "insert into d1 select min(x), max(x) from d2", 
        "select * from d1"))
```

The output is

```
       min_x     max_x
1 0.05290026 0.9427019
```

Now I want to use d1 in my R code, but if I enter

```
d1
```

R responds

```
> d1
Error: object 'd1' not found
```

I have tried this using SQLite and RH2 with the same results.

How do I use d1 in R?

Comment: You can assign the output of `sqldf` to an object and then use it.

Comment: Interesting, because when I run your code, the value of d1 is 24.18729.

Comment: I tried it again today after rebooting my computer and got the same results.  I even tried creating d1 in R as a dataframe, but then I got an error message from sqldf that d1 already existed. So I deleted the code to create table d1 and ran it again.  The SQL insert "works" and shows all the records, but d1 in R shows just the original data.  In the SQL d1, should be a row with two values, both < 10.

Answer (score 1):

sqldf, when used with the default driver SQLite will setup an on-the-fly in-memory database which will be destroyed upon exit. The only way to save the object is to assign it with :

```
d1 <- sqldf(c("create table d1(min_x real, max_x real)", 
    "insert into d1 select min(x), max(x) from d2", 
    "select * from d1"))
```

You can then use it in your R code:

```
> print(d1)
  min_x     max_x
1 0.0558218 0.8966438
```